# How to limit webui to localhost and deliver playback URLs on https port?

Tags: webui, ant-media-server-sdk

Web UI should only happen via ssh tunnel.

There was no option to try to limit as such.

Answer (score 0):

You can use IP Filter for the Web Panel to limit access to the AMS web panel,i.e., UI

To do so, Open `/usr/local/antmedia/conf/red5.properties` file.

The default configuration lets all IPs access the Web panel.

```
server.allowed_dashboard_CIDR=0.0.0.0/0
```

Change the configuration according to your CIDR notation. You can add comma-separated CIDR notations as well.

```
server.allowed_dashboard_CIDR=13.197.23.11/16,87.22.34.66/8
```

Save the file and restart the server with `sudo service antmedia restart`

Now only the IPs that are in the CIDR block can access the Web panel.